# How can I change the imageview image in a fragment based on the text in a edittext from my activity_main

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a textbox in my activity_main.xml and I would like to change the content of the imageview held within a fragment based on the text in the textbox.

I have tried reading in the text from the field (ChangeFragment function) and parsing it into a ChangeImage function which has some if functions to change the content of the imageview based on the parsed in text.

**EditDataActivity.java**

```
package com.example.attempttwo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "EditDataActivity";

    private Button btnSave,btnDelete, btnImage;
    private EditText editable_item;

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    private String selectedName;
    private int selectedID;

    public String edit_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewImage);

        editable_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

        //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
        selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

        //now get the name we passed as an extra
        selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

        //set the text to show the current selected name
        editable_item.setText(selectedName);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String item = editable_item.getText().toString();
                if(!item.equals("")){
                    mDatabaseHelper.updateName(item,selectedID,selectedName);
                }else{
                    toastMessage("You must enter a name");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
                editable_item.setText("");
                toastMessage("removed from database");
            }
        });
    }

    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void ChangeFragment(View view){
        Fragment fragment;
        //FragmentTwo fTwo = new FragmentTwo();
        edit_name = editable_item.getText().toString();

        //Checking the text is getting read properly
        Toast.makeText(this, edit_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if( view == findViewById(R.id.btnViewImage)){
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            ((FragmentTwo) fragment).ChangeImage(edit_name);

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }if( view == findViewById(R.id.btnClose)){
            fragment = new FragmentImage();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
package com.example.attempttwo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentTwo#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    ViewGroup rootView;
    ImageView imgView;

    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentTwo.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentTwo newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        imgView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    public void ChangeImage(String edit_name){
        if(edit_name == "Sabo"){
                ImageView img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sabo);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } if (edit_name == "Tsunade"){
                ImageView img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tsunade);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } if(edit_name == "Tanjiro"){
                ImageView img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tanjiro);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } if(edit_name == "Saitama"){
                ImageView img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.saitama);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } if(edit_name == "Boruto"){
                ImageView img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.boruto);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/13685592
You can just create a bundle and pass your string using that Bundle to the Fragment activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a static function that returns the ID of the resource you are looking for following what is in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
public static int getResourceIDByName(Context context, String name, String defType, String defPackage) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error to getting Resource id for "+name, e);
    }
}
```

and, to obtain the reference ID of the resource in Fragment, you can call the function as follows

```
getResourceIDByName(getActivity(), "iconName", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

with your example:

```
public void ChangeImage(String edit_name){
    try {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);
        int resourseID = getResourceIDByName(getActivity(), edit_name, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(resourseID);
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        //TODO Handler error
    }
}
```

Remember to handle the exception at run time

Read the documentation before deciding to use this method, there is the following note there:
*use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.*

Comment: Please read also about name conventions use in Java code
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html